# How to use a rectangle shape background with TextView in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-drawable

I designed an app on adobe xd and I exported some assests in my drawable folder on android studio. In my activity xml, I added the TextView background as the rectangle shape in my drawable. It worked but when I tried aligning the text but not the shape nothing happens. I guess I can't separate the text from the background

Comment: Could you provide some images of the problem that you're facing?

Answer (score 0):

don't use a picture as background create a drawable file and use it as background

for example, create TextViewBackground.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/Color_White_4" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
  </shape>
```

and use this in your TextView

```
<TextView
.
.
.
android:background="@drawable/TextViewBackground"/>
```

try to create custom TextView

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Login_Username_TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Login_Title"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/TextViewBackground">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Login_Username_Hint"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="38dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="@string/User_Name"
                android:textColorHint="@color/Color_Gray_1"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Login_Username_Text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/Login_Username_Hint"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:lines="1"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:textColor="@color/Color_Gray_1"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah I did and I changed the width to 291dp and height to 44dp. But the text just stays at the top left corner, can't move it to where I want

Comment: Trying to create a login activity. The username should have a rectangular shape background to input the text

Comment: try to create your custom text view 
check my answer☝☝☝